# Creating a github remote branch

Tags: github

Why i'm unable to create a branch on remote.I'm using this command `git push --set-upstream origin mybranch`
There is no error message on terminal. It asks for email and pass. But when I refresh github.com. There is no branch other than 'master'[image: Notice the bottom section of the terminal]

Answer (score 1):

The branch is there in github.Click on the `branches` link[image]

Comment: First checkout to a different branch other than the one you want to delete. Then execute `git branch -d <branch-name>`.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are not pushing to the right remote branch. Try -

`git push test-1 master`